# Where to find Magento database

Tags: mysql, database, magento

I'm trying to access my Magento database. That's because I would like to delete all orders, customers and stuff. Do you know I can access it? I tried going to www.domain.com/phpmyadmin/ but I can't find anything here. I already have this credentials: host, username, password, dbname, found them in file local.xml

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. My server is on Jelastic and I solved going into the Jelastic -> database -> database node -> addictionally -> info -> click to admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to do in database. As Per my understanding:

**Delete all orders, customers and stuff From Database:**

Magento stores data in EAV and Flat table format like order data is split in multiple tables. Deleting data from tables cause many problems and increase redundancy in your database. Best way is You can install the extension to delete orders from magento backend. and magento already have function to delete customers, products etc.

**Access my Magento database:**

You need to login in cPanel to access Phpmyadmin. It is possible to access database like this way ( www.domain.com/phpmyadmin/ ) as well. but in this phpmyadmin directory must in your site root and allowed by host to access directly using username password. So there are three ways to access database:

1. Login in cPanel and clieck on phpmyadmin to access DB
2. Ask Host for Database direct URL and use your DB username, password to access DB
3. download third party software like `mysql workbench` to access DB. In this case you may need to white list your IP address in cPanel

Answer (score 0):

hope this suggestion helpful for you

rather than deleting record from database

try from magneto admin to delete records

www.yourdomain.com/admin

to manage orders
go to sales->orders from admin panel

for customer management
got customers->manage customers